# Angular img from response

Tags: angular, wordpress-rest-api

I have response array with picture and some text. I show it on the site using *ngFor:

```
 <div *ngFor="let post of allPosts">
  <img src="{{post.better_featured_image.source_url}}" alt="">
  <h2>{{ post.title.rendered }}</h2>
 </div>
```

Sometimes when loading a site, pictures are not displayed on the page, then I in DevTools for the img set style - `display: block;` the picture was appears, but when reload page, it may again disappear.

If I add in the style.css `display: block;` -> the problem is not solved.

It looks like the picture sometimes gets style `display: none;`

**Add after 5 min...**
In **style.css** img was

```
.stock img {width: 370px;height: 100%;}
```

I deleted `height: 100%;` and it looks like the problem has disappeared.

Comment: Pictures have to load before being displayed. Sometimes, they can take time. Is that your issue ?

Comment: Pictures take time to load, you can use placeholder approach to see if its really not rendering or is it just loading issue.

Answer (score 0):

try using square brackets for **src**:-

```
 <div *ngFor="let post of allPosts">
  <img [src]="{{post.better_featured_image.source_url}}" alt="">
  <h2>{{ post.title.rendered }}</h2>
 </div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Problem was in style.css in line `height: 100%;`